# Configure varnish with cloudflare along with SSL terminator

Tags: ssl, varnish, cloudflare

Our present scenario:
[Present Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBhtx.png)

Now, we are planning to create a cache server between the user and the site.
[Proposed Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7vT5.png)

As per my understanding, cache servers can't work with HTTPs data. So, we have to convert the data from https to http. For this reason, we can use two SSL terminations for this conversion.
[Varnish with SSL termination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAyDb.png)

I can configure the SSL between the user and the varnish server. But I am not understanding how I will configure the termination in between Varnish and Cloudflare for HTTPs to HTTP conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Varnish Cache, the open source version of Varnish, doesn't support TLS.

You can offload incoming TLS requests from the client using a TLS proxy like Hitch. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/ for a tutorial on how to install & configure it.

However, Varnish doesn't support backend TLS connections either. This means the connection between Varnish and Cloudflare will also happen over plain HTTP.

### Transmitting protocol information to the other servers

Given that all traffic is transmitted over plain HTTP once the TLS connection is terminated by your TLS proxy, the metadata about the initial client connection needs to be transmitted.

My initial suggestion would be to enable the PROXY protocol on all proxy servers in the chain. This means:

- Enable a PROXY protocol listening interface on Varnish
- Send traffic from Hitch to Varnish over the PROXY protocol
- Send traffic from Varnish to Cloudflare over the PROXY protocol

This ensures that client connection information is accounted for across all hops.

But just to be safe, I would also set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header in Varnish based on the PROXY information. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/#retrieve-tls-information-with-vmod_proxy for the exact VCL code to get it done

See https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/http-request-headers/#x-forwarded-proto for Cloudflare's take on `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

If you have a Cloudflare enterprise plan, you can also receive PROXY protocol requests in Cloudflare. See https://developers.cloudflare.com/spectrum/how-to/enable-proxy-protocol/ for more info.

Just add the `.proxy_header = 2;` attribute to your backend in `default.vcl`
to enable the PROXY protocol for backend connections.

If you don't have a Cloudflare enterprise plan, maybe using `X-Forwarded-Proto` is the way to go.

### TLS support in Varnish Enterprise

If you want to have end-to-end TLS support in Varnish, you can purchase a subscription with Varnish Software for the Varnish Enterprise product.

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-enterprise/features/backend-ssl/ for documentation about backend TLS support in Varnish Enterprise.

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-enterprise/features/core-ssl/ for in-core TLS support in Varnish Enterprise.